# splitting a string by multiple delimitters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a set of addresses:

```
34 Main St Suite 23
435 Center Road Ste 3
34 Jack Corner Bldg 4
2 Some Street Building 345
```

the delimitters would be:

```
Suite, Ste, Bldg, Building
```

I would like to separate these addresses into `address1` and `address2` like this:

```
+---------------------+--------------+
|      Address1       |   Address2   |
+---------------------+--------------+
| 34 Main St          | Suite 23     |
| 435 Center Road     | Ste 3        |
| 34 Jack Corner      | Bldg 4       |
| 2 Some Street       | Building 345 |
+---------------------+--------------+
```

How can I define a set of delimitters and delimit in this fashion?

Comment: Shouldn't the first row for `Address1` be `34 Main St`

Comment: I have seen many examples of how to split a string, but i have not found anything that can split on a set of strings

Comment: You could use regular expressions with `dbo.RegExMatch` to perform this task (this link could help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)

Comment: @FranciscoSpaeth thanks so much can you show me how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
   T.Address,
   Left(T.Address, IsNull(X.Pos - 1, 2147483647)) Address1,
   Substring(T.Address, X.Pos + 1, 2147483647) Address2 -- Null if no second
FROM
   (
      VALUES
      ('34 Main St Suite 23'),
      ('435 Center Road Ste 3'),
      ('34 Jack Corner Bldg 4'),
      ('2 Some Street Building 345'),
      ('123 Sterling Rd'),
      ('405 29th St Bldg 4 Ste 217')
   ) T (Address)
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 NullIf(PatIndex(Delimiter, T.Address), 0) Pos
      FROM (
         VALUES ('% Suite %'), ('% Ste %'), ('% Bldg %'), ('% Building %')
      ) X (Delimiter)
      WHERE T.Address LIKE X.Delimiter 
      ORDER BY Pos
   ) X
```

I used `PatIndex()` so an address like "Sterling Rd" won't give you a false match on "Ste"

Result set:

```
Address1         Address2
---------------  --------
34 Main St       Suite 23
435 Center Road  Ste 3
34 Jack Corner   Bldg 4
2 Some Street    Building 345
123 Sterling Rd  NULL
405 29th St      Bldg 4 Ste 217
```

Comment: erik thank you so much, however its not working with 20950 N. Tatum Blvd., Ste 300 or 1524 McHenry Ave Ste 470  (just some examples)

Comment: wow this is unbelievably amazing, you are a genius. this code is a piece of art! thank you so much for your kindness

Answer (score 1):

You can use a table of delimiters on which to perform your split.  In this example I am using XML to do the parsing, but after you've swapped in a reliable delimiter in place of your set (Ste, Suite, etc.) then you can perform the splitting using any of many t-sql based methods.

```
declare @tab table (s varchar(100))
insert into @tab
    select '34 Main St Suite 23' union all
    select '435 Center Road Ste 3' union all
    select '34 Jack Corner Bldg 4' union all
    select '2 Some Street Building 345' union all
    select '20950 N. Tatum Blvd., Ste 300' union all
    select '1524 McHenry Ave Ste 470';

declare @delimiters table (d varchar(100));
insert into @delimiters
    select 'Suite' union all
    select 'Ste' union all
    select 'Bldg' union all
    select 'Building';

select  s, 
        cast('<r>'+ replace(s, d, '</r><r>'+d) + '</r>' as xml),
        [Street1] = cast('<r>'+ replace(s, d, '</r><r>'+d) + '</r>' as xml).value('r[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
        [Street2] = cast('<r>'+ replace(s, d, '</r><r>'+d) + '</r>' as xml).value('r[2]', 'varchar(100)')
from    @tab t
cross
apply   @delimiters d 
where   charindex(' '+d+' ', s) > 0;
```

Comment: getting INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR CAST on this line cast('<r>'+ replace(s, d, '</r><r>'+d) + '</r>' as xml),

Comment: No syntax errors for me. But try this address: `405 29th St Bldg 4 Ste 217`. You'll find the wrong result is returned. Also, try `123 Sterling St`.

Comment: @ErikE Multiple delims were not on the menu! :)

Comment: @NathanSkerl Try the second one

Comment: Ok, made it so delimited must be lead/followed by space for second case

Comment: i just looked at this again, pretty brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

```
select Addr,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('suite',addr,1)>0 then LEFT(addr,CHARINDEX('suite',addr,1)-1)
            WHEN CHARINDEX('Ste',addr,1)>0 then LEFT(addr,CHARINDEX('Ste',addr,1)-1) 
            WHEN CHARINDEX('Bldg',addr,1)>0 then LEFT(addr,CHARINDEX('Bldg',addr,1)-1)
            WHEN CHARINDEX('Building',addr,1)>0 then LEFT(addr,CHARINDEX('Building',addr,1)-1)
            END as [Address],

            CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('suite',addr,1)>0 then RIGHT(addr,len(addr)-(CHARINDEX('suite',addr,1)-1))
            WHEN CHARINDEX('Ste',addr,1)>0 then RIGHT(addr,len(addr)-(CHARINDEX('Ste',addr,1)-1))
            WHEN CHARINDEX('Bldg',addr,1)>0 then RIGHT(addr,len(addr)-(CHARINDEX('Bldg',addr,1)-1))
            WHEN CHARINDEX('Building',addr,1)>0 then RIGHT(addr,len(addr)-(CHARINDEX('Building',addr,1)-1))
            END as [Address1]

 from Addr
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're going to try to parse this data, and it's NOT going to be delimited by something (ie comma), it's going to be much harder and you will have to make some assumptions. Having a larger data set can help you make stronger assumptions, but it will still be very brittle.

Looking at your data, I think you can make the following assumptions:
1) Address 2 is always the last 2 words (when split with spaces), so you could split the address based on spaces, and use the last 2 as Address 2, and the rest as Address 1.
2) You can assume Address 1 is the first 3 words, and the rest is Address 2.

To split up this data, I would either use T-SQL equivalent of split(' ', $data) to get an array of the words. Or, use a T-SQL equivalent of strpos and strrpos to find the 2nd to last space, or the position of the 3rd space, and substr everything before and after that into the appropriate variables.

It's up to you to make the decision based on the data available to pick the more robust assumptions and work with them.

Comment: I don't think assumption 1 is safe, because what about addresses that don't have a Suite?

Comment: Well that would definitely have to be taken into consideration. Based off the data you provided, it's fine. But obviously there are probably many alterations that we (me) cannot see.